# Реализация вычитания массивов

Tags: java, массивы

Помогите с реализацией метода `minus()` , который принимает параметры 2 массива arr1 и arr2. В результате должен возвращать разницу между двумя массивами.

Пояснение что в моем понимание разница - вернуть массив,  элементы которого содержаться в arr1, но не и в arr2.

Comment: Что в вашем понимании разница массивов? Операция, аналогичная разности множеств? В чем загвоздка в таком случае? Создаете третий массив, внешний цикл по одному массиву, внутренний по второму, проверяете если элемент первого массива равен второму, значит эти два элемента в разность не включать. Если за один проход по второму циклу не нашли равный элемент, то добавляете текущий элемент первого массива в массив-разность...
Приведите пример входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Таки да - понятие "разница массивов" не раскрыто. Засим ответить вам невозможно в принципе.

Comment: Да и более того, а что-то вы пытались сделать или это испытание для обитателей ruSO?

Comment: Как мне показалось, речь идёт о простой операции вычитания из элементов одного массива значений элементов другого массива.

Comment: @DimXenon не факт. может разницу а-ля diff? а может сумма элементов в одном минус сумма в другом, а может еще чего

Comment: Возможно. Подождём уточнений.

Comment: @Александр Дерменжи странно, в вопросе вы говорите, `вернуть массив, элементы которого содержаться в arr1, но нет`, а отмечаете ответ, в котором просто нет дупликатов......странно как-то

Comment: Исправил, действительно мне не подходит данный вариант

Comment: @АлександрДерменжи если у вас простенькая задача, то можно вместо массивов использовать Коллекции и в частности использовать метод `removeAll`. А вот если у вас действительно массивы и жестко на них завязаны и логика уже есть всего для них - будет совсем другое решение.....но интересно было бы, что у вас есть и что вы пытались сделать

Comment: На самом деле вопрос собеседования, который меня затруднил. Больше в задании ничего нет.

Answer (score 2):

1. Проверяем, что массивы одного типа (это как входные данные метода - делается автоматом).
2. Проверяем, что они оба не null.
3. Проверяем их длину. Длину максимального сохраняем в буферную целочисленную переменную (int arrayLength).
   3.1. Создаём буферный массив (если контейнерами не пользуемся) для результата - длина массива равна arrayLength.
4. Начинаем цикл от 0 до arrayLength-1;
5. Если значение счётчика циклов < длины меньшего массива (можно её тоже сохранить), то выполняем вычитание значения второго массива из значения первого массива. Сохраняем результат в буферный массив под тем же индексом.
6. Если значение счётчика циклов больше длины меньшего массива - просто производим вычитание значения из нуля. Иначе - записываем значение из первого массива.
7. Возвращаем буферный массив (понятно, что ссылку на него) как результат.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем за мысли. Думаю все таки решение будет через коллекции. Вот что у меня получилось.

```
public static Integer[] minus(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2){

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr2));
    list1.removeAll(list2);
    Integer[] array = list1.toArray(new Integer[list1.size()]);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Можно чуточку сократить код, сразу вернув `list1.toArray(new Integer[list1.size()]);`.

Comment: `list2` не нужен - в метод `removeAll` можно сразу `Arrays.asList(...)` передать.